# Asp.net prevent modal popup to get displayed while clicking on browser back button

Tags: asp.net

GoodEvening Everyone,

I am having one asp.net application which contains many links. some of the link displays modal popup Now if i move to link which nabvigates me and click on browser back button so modal popup gets display which i dont want. i need the previous page should get displayed instead of modal popup if i click on browser back button

for example

i clicked on link1 - navigated to page2

i clicked on link2 - displayed modal popup

i click on link3 - navigated to page3

Now if i click on browser back button so modal popup get displays instead of which i want the page2(previous page before the modal popup ) should get displayed.

So please let me know is this possible and how its possible.

It will be appreciated if some one provide me code to do this...

Let me know in case of more information required

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons this might be happening.

1. It might be that you are setting some state flags that persist between pages that influence the modal popups visibility. If you need help with this we will need some more details and preferably code samples.
2. It might be a browser caching issue. When you hit the back button the browser might be fetching the page from it's cache (not the server) with the popup visible. To test this you could disable the browsers cache and run through your process. If this proves to be the reason you can disable browser caching for your site by adding some meta tags (you'll find the exact tags on Google easily)

Comment: Hi ... i tried with the point 2 but it release the whole cache whereas i just want to release the cache of modal popup..when i click on browser back button so modal popup is getting display instead the previous page should get loaded.. Also i am sharing sample code so that you can get an better idea

please find the sample code below for your understanding and reply asap 


 protected void gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        { sample functions that call modalpopup show() function
}


let me know in case of more info needed
}

Comment: Code 
if (e.CommandName == "GetDetails")
            {
                Guid UseId = Guid.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                getDetails.UserDetails(UseId, e.CommandName);
            }

In gridview rowcommand event above code has been added. in which getdetails is and usercontrol 
which calls userdetails function and modal popup gets displayed by calling this function

Comment: @nilesh - I am facing the same prob. Wot is the solution? Thanks.